# Where is CRS of shapefile defined?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

The geometry of the coordinates are defined inside a shapefile.

Without referencing a CRS the coordinates have only a little meaning.

Is the CRS defined inside the .dbf, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .prj file normally conatins the CRS for a shapefile.
See here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/shapefile-file-extensions.htm